# Unable to Copy Changes Back Using git-difftool with Beyond Compare 4/Meld

Tags: git, meld, git-difftool, beyondcompare4

I have been using [git-difftool](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool) along with Beyond Compare 4 and Meld to review and revert changes in the working directory. While this process works smoothly for most files, I have encountered an issue where certain files do not have their changes copied back from the temporary directory used for comparison. Here are the details of my setup and the problem:

- Operating System: Windows 11 Enterprise (Version 22H2)
- Git Version: 2.42.0.windows.1
- Diff Tools: Beyond Compare 4 and Meld 3.22.0

I tried to use multiple diff tools and read the documentation git-difftool command (e.g., I tried to use symlinks, but they seem to be not supported in Windows' version of git). Despite my attempts, I am still encountering this issue.